# Unable to push to Dockerhub via Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerhub

```
pipeline {
         agent any
         stages {

                 stage('Checkout') {
                 steps {
                     echo 'Retrieving Jenkinsfile from the github repository.'
                   checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'dummy']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/humblemetsuke/coursework_2']]])
                 }
                 }

        stage('SonarQube') {
    environment {
        scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube'
    }
    steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
            sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
        }
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
            waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
        }
    }
}

stage ('build docker image') {

steps {
echo 'Beginning to build the docker image.'

script {

 dockerImage= docker.build("coursework_2:${env.BUILD_ID}")

         }
}

}

stage ('push docker image to DockerHub') {

steps {
echo 'Beginning to push the built docker image to Dockerhub.'

script {

withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'e1984af9-1751-4825-883a-9194875c8f89', url: '') {


         }
         dockerImage.push()
}

}

}
}
}
```

I have enclosed my Jenkins file. Everytime I run it, I am told:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I thought perhaps this was a Docker login issue. I delibrately entered the wrong credentials, and was presented with a message that the username or password was incorrect, so was able to eliminate that (and helped to assure me that the login was succesful was not a false positive). However, I am at a loss as to what is going wrong, and why I am not getting the desired result, namely, that the image is being pushed to Dockerhub.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your jenkinsfile as a code block directly in your question. This is an overall good practice so that all info is available at a glance. Moreover, pastebin (for very challengeable reasons...) is blocked on several corporate networks in the world.

Comment: dockerImage.push() is out of a context of a Docker Regitry where it will be pushed?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line `dockerImage.push()` be inside the braces of `withDockerRegistry`? Or is it accidentally left outside in your code sample above?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [2 Factor Authentication](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/2fa/) and/or are you using [Personal Access Tokens](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/) for your Docker password in this Jenkins Job?

If so, it's possible Jenkins utilizes some aspects of the DockerHub API (and not the docker CLI) which has some caveats.  See one particular one reported by me today here: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1927